# Mocking service method that requires two streams to be open at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq

I'm trying to Moq a method that requires 2 streams. IE: StreamReader and StreamWriter. However, when I run my test I can't seem to get passed an exception that is being thrown by the compiler. Each time I run the test I come across a System.IO.IOException as the steam is being used by another process.

```
public void LoadStockLevels(string reportId)
{
    //read file line by line
    CreateRequiredFiles(reportId);
    _updateItemList = new List<IStockLevelItem>();
    _updateAttributeItemList = new List<AttributeItem>();

    try
    {
        _sr = _streamReaderWrapper.GetStreamReader(_report + reportId + ".xml");
        while ((_line = _sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //sync stock levels
            var stockItem = _line.Split('\t');
            if (stockItem[0] != "sku")
            {
                _updateItemList.Add(new StockLevelItem()
                {
                    Identifier = stockItem[1],
                    Sku = stockItem[0],
                    Quantity = stockItem[3]
                });
                _updateAttributeItemList.Add(new AttributeItem()
                {
                    AttributeValue = stockItem[1],
                    AttributeKey = "IDENT"
                });
            }
            else
            {
                _wsr = _streamWriterWrapper.GetStreamWriter(_inventoryFile, true);
                _wsr.WriteLine(
                    "sku    price   minimum-seller-allowed-price    maximum-seller-allowed-price    quantity    leadtime-to-ship");
                _wsr.Close();
            }
        }
        _sr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if(_sr != null) _sr.Close();
        if (_wsr != null) _wsr.Close();
        _log.Error("Failed to load stock levels", ex);
    }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
[Test]
public void Test_LoadStockLevels_CatchesException()
{
    using (var stream1 = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var bmp1 = new Bitmap(1, 1))
        {
            var graphics1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1);
            graphics1.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            bmp1.Save(stream1, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        _streamWriterWrapper.Setup(s => s.GetStreamWriter(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
        .Returns(new StreamWriter(stream1.ToString(), true));

    }

    using (var stream2 = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var bmp2 = new Bitmap(1, 1))
        {
            var graphics2 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);
            graphics2.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            bmp2.Save(stream2, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        _streamReaderWrapper.Setup(s => s.GetStreamReader(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(new StreamReader(stream2.ToString()));
        // Assert something with postedFile here 
        _stockSyncService = new StockSyncService(_stockSync.Object, _tService.Object, _features.Object,
            _macduffClient.Object, _configManager.Object, _streamReaderWrapper.Object, _streamWriterWrapper.Object);
        var result = _stockSyncService.LoadStockLevels("504978");
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<StreamWriter>(result);
    }
}
```

I know the question of mocking a stream has been answered but I'm not sure this question has been asked.

Is it possible to mock out a test that is required to use 2 streams with a memory stream.

/** Edit: Added StackTrace **/

```
Test 'StockIntergration.Services.Tests.StockSync.StockSyncServiceTests.Test_LoadStockLevels_CatchesException' failed:
    System.IO.IOException : The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\ianrichards\Documents\Repositories\StockIntergration\StockIntergration.Services.Tests\bin\Debug\System.IO.MemoryStream' because it is being used by another process.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
    at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
    at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path)
    StockSync\StockSyncServiceTests.cs(199,0): at StockIntergration.Services.Tests.StockSync.StockSyncServiceTests.Test_LoadStockLevels_CatchesException()

0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 3.71 seconds (NUnit 2.6.2).
```

Comment: What this `new StreamWriter(stream1.ToString(), true))` code supposed to do?

Comment: Please also add complete message (with couple lines of stack trace too).

Answer (score 0):

Try this test without using. There mighyt be a problem with stream being disposed. Remove usings and manualy close and dispose stream at the end of test.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is the culprit:

```
     new StreamWriter(stream1.ToString(), true))
```

`ToString` on most classes returns class name and it is exactly what exception shows - `new StreamReader("MemoryStream", true)` tries to create file in current folder with given name and fails.

You are looking for creating another `MemoryStream` over byte array of first one:

```
new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream(stream1.ToArray(), false)));
```